# Python NameError: name method_name is not defined

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I tried to call a method from within a class like this,

```
from tkinter import * 

class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    # initialize the login screen UI  
    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Login Screen")


    def make_label(parent, caption=NONE, side=TOP, **options):
        label = Label(parent, text=caption, **options)

        if side is not TOP:
            label.pack(side=side)
        else:
            label.pack()

        return label


    def main():
        top = Tk()

        # create a background image 
        photo_bg = PhotoImage(file="building.gif")          
        building = make_label(top, image=photo_bg)

        top.mainloop()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I got an error`NameError: name 'make_label' is not defined`, how to resolve this. Also I tried to make the code as importable as possible, to run as a module, what's the best way to do that?

many thanks

Comment: I think something went wrong with the indentation when you pasted your code, please [edit] the code to fix that. Is `make_label` supposed to be a function or a class method? I suspect the latter? If so, then you need to use `ClassInstance.make_label()` or `self.make_label()` (from inside the class instance). You're never actually making a `LoginFrame` class instance anywhere btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to reference the method of a class, so you need to reference the class and then reference the method within the scope of that class like so:

```
building = LoginFrame.make_label(top, image=photo_bg)
```

As for import-ability, using classes and functions like you have looks fine to me. If you `import` this then the code within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement won't be run when it is imported as it is not the initial python script to be run (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)) but the functions and classes of this script can still be referenced.

Comment: it is actually the indentation I put in the code was wrong, `main` and `if` statement should not be indented